# How to represent my data

Tags: sql, xml

I need some opinions here on the best thing to do.  My project touches all the computers in a network and reads important values.
Example:

```
<scan><host><configuration><host_name>192.168.73.31</host_name></configuration> 
<requested_scans><user_info> 
    <user> 
        <name>Administrator</name> 
        <password_age>23492718</password_age> 
        <password_age_human_readable>271d 21h 45m 18s</password_age_human_readable> 
...
    </user></user_info> 
<computer_info> 
    <computer_name>XP11</computer_name> 
    <system_directory>C:\WINDOWS\system32</system_directory> 
    <windows_directory>C:\WINDOWS</windows_directory> 
    <computer_name_netbios>XP11</computer_name_netbios> 
...
```

The end goal is to provide the user with tables where he/she can filter out things that he/she doesn't want to see.
i.e. Show me no more entries where autorun_program.name == Adobe Rader && autorun_program.location == c:\program files\adobe\reader\areader.exe

I'm thinking that the clients should send out xml like you see above, then load that into a db, then use a table for filters to create exclusions.

Already using Sqlite.  Each scan can have its own db.  The important thing I have to deal with is version skew.  That's why I thought, generating an SQL schema based on the XML output might be a good way to deal with it.  Everything dynamic.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine used a language called XSL, which I can't say I'm particularly familiar with, but it introduces client-side browser scripting with XML as the source. So, in essence, if the data is static, it'd be quick and easy to throw together some sort of view to be associated with the files. Again, I'm not extremely familiar with it, but it sounds like it may suit your needs.

Comment: It's not appropriate for my solution.  I am using xslt to do some things.